# Convert string to date laravel excel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-excel

Hi I have a problem for date time format

when I set a string to date like this

```
$row['waktu_awal'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($discharge->waktu_awal));
```

Format text/string change to date but in excel format not change to date

like this picture

[image: Excel]

Any solution to this case?

Thanks

Comment: to generate Excel what are the plugin you using ?

Comment: You are using from collection or query or what?

Comment: @Hamelraj use maatwebsite/laravel-excel

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur

I use query builder for execute stored procedure

here is my code

https://pastebin.com/pZrHekBC

Comment: Problem is here

https://www.imageupload.net/image/format-excel-date.CLCLp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$row['waktu_awal'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($discharge->waktu_awal));
$row['waktu_awal'] = Date::dateTimeToExcel(Carbon::parse($row['waktu_awal']));
```

);

and you can format from the column use:

```
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME,
    ];
}
```

reference:
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html

Comment: Hi i have error when try this

$row['waktu_awal'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($discharge->waktu_awal));
$row['waktu_awal'] = Date::dateTimeToExcel($row['waktu_awal']);

Argument 1 passed to PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::dateTimeToExcel() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, string given, called in

@MuhammadDyasYaskur

Comment: My update code 
https://pastebin.com/DEGHJmGg

@MuhammadDyasYaskur

Comment: @TemmyAlex try `Carbon::parse($row['waktu_awal'])`